# Start-Process cmdlet with -ArgumentList throw "Invalid Argument" error

Tags: powershell

I want to register a dll using `gacutil.exe`.

```
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" -ArgumentList '/u', "USB\CRM\Common"
```

It throw the error:
[image]

Comment: Either you provide the arguments to the executable formatted as one big string or you have to seperate them with commata. The screenshot shows that you forgot the comma.

Comment: Silly me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `Start-Process` if you just want to run a command at the PowerShell command line. PowerShell can run commands typed at its prompt. (It's a shell; one of the purposes of a shell is to run commands you enter.) Since the command contains spaces, enclose it in `"` and execute it with the `&` (call or invocation) operator.

```
& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools\gacutil.exe" /u USB\CRM\Common
```